# Find the least value of $b$ such that any permutation of given numbers can be expressed as $a^b$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, integers

Today  a question about number theory just popped out in my mind.

> Consider all the the permutations of one $1$, two $2$'s,  three $3$'s,..... , nine $9$'s. Can any of its permutation be ever expressed in the form of $a^b$ such that $a$ and $b$ are both natural numbers.  I want to find the least value of $b$ for which at least one of the permutation can be expressed in form $a^b$.

I have tried up-to $13^{th}$ powers using the residue mod  $9$ but none of them was $\equiv 6\pmod 9$. Can someone please share some thoughts over it.

Comment: Heuristically, probably. There are $$\binom{45}{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} \approx 10^{34.8}$$ numbers with that digit distribution, and approximately 1 in $10^{22.5}$ of them should be a square. Finding one, on the other hand...

Comment: @Peter Taylor How can you say there would be one square $10^{22.5}$. I have already proved that there won't be any perfect square in any of these permutations.

Comment: I didn't say that there *would* be: I said that heuristically there *should* be. Nevertheless, heuristics sometimes have obstacles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heuristically, it looks promising. There are $$\binom{45}{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} \approx 10^{34.8}$$ numbers with that digit distribution and approximately $1$ in $10^{22.5}$ should be a square, and $1$ in $10^{30}$ should be a cube.

However, you make a good observation about values modulo $9$.

$1^1 + 2^2 + \ldots + 9^2 \equiv 6 \pmod 9$, and $a^b \equiv 6 \pmod 9$ clearly has no integer solutions for $b > 1$ since $a$ would clearly have to be a multiple of $3$, but then $a^b$ is a multiple of $9$.

Comment: How did you conclude that $a$ must be multiple of 3. At first you proved that for $a^b \equiv 6\pmod 9$ $a$ must multiple of 3 but again you say that it would leave  0 as remainder on dividing by 9. What do you mean to say exactly?

Comment: $a^b \equiv 6 \pmod 9$ is shorthand for $\exists k: a^b = 6 + 9k$. Since the RHS is divisible by 3, so is the LHS. But every prime which divides $a^b$ must divide $a$.

Comment: Gotcha I got it.